# TYPO3 7.6 powermail - restrict access for editor to forms in his pagetree

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, access-rights, powermail

editors which have access to the plugin "powermail" have access to all of the forms. Since it is a multidomain-installation the editors should have only access to the forms of their domain.

I thought the limitation of access-rights should be enough, but all editors have access to all forms - independent of the domain and pagetree.

Any hints?

Thanks

Kerstin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powermail 3.8 or newer editors can only select form that are stored on pages where they have access to automatically.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/FilterFormSelection/Index.html

Restrict by PageTS, for example:

```
#Show only Forms from the same page where the plugin is stored (and all subpages)
tx_powermail.flexForm.formSelection = current

# Show Forms from page 46 (and all subpages)
tx_powermail.flexForm.formSelection = 46

# Show Forms from page 46,49 and the current page where the plugin is stored (and all their subpages)
tx_powermail.flexForm.formSelection = 46,49,current
```

Comment: please mark your answer as solution as well, thanks!

Comment: I tried yesterday, but it is a rule on stackoverflow that I can my own answer as solution after two days ... will do tomorrow.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/